# Praat: Interpretation of row number when inspecting sound file

Tags: praat, acoustic-analysis, frequency

When I inspect a sound file in Praat, I see the following picture:

[image]

I understand that Praat creates a ny x nx matrix using these values, and that 'nx' refers to the number of frames in the WAV file. But what does 'ny' refer to?

In addition, I observe that both y values for each frame are equal. Why is this so, and does this have any implications for the accuracy of frequency estimation?

Comment: There is a help documentation in  Praat: http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Matrix.html

Comment: @amegnunsen Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, that link does not state what the row values refer to.

Comment: The answer is given in the help documentation. See the examples below. In short, it depends on your signal. These symbols refer to a matrix. This matrix can describe either a sound, so at the intersection of any nx and any ny, there is the amplitude value. Or If the matrix describes a FFT, so there is the formant value.